# How to render only one document in jade view?

Tags: node.js, json, express, pug

I need to display only one document from my CouchDB, but if I don't create for-each loop, I can't define variable employer

```
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-8
      .row.list-group 
        each employer in the employers
          .col-xs-12.list-group-item
            h4 
              p #{employer.value.name}, #{employer.value.location} #{employer.value.type}, #{employeer.value.position}
              small &nbsp;
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4 
      p.lead= sidebar
```

When I try to display only one document without the loop, I am receiving an error:  Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

If `employeers` is an array, you should be able to do something like:

```
employeers[0].value.name
```

If you want to keep using "employer" you can also replace your each loop with:

```
- var employer = employeers[0];
```

Comment: res.render('detailedjobs',{employeers:data.data.rows}); where detailedjobs is my view and employeers makes connection to my database.

Comment: Try this:
res.render('detailedjobs',{employer:data.data.rows[0]});

This will assign only one value from your data to the variable employer.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much! If I want my view to display different documents, should I make a loop?

Comment: Well "each employer in employeers" is a foreach loop...
But, in your example you wrote "each employer in the employeers".   The word **the** will cause you problems because the pug engine will try to look for the value of **the** which is undefined.

Comment: And not to be the grammar police, but you spell employers with only one e.  ;)

Comment: Maybe this can help you with your pug loop: 
https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: I am sorry for my mistakes! I appreciate your help! I will have on mind what you told me.